# Reversed ssh tunnel w/ socks

Tags: ssh, proxy, socks

My situation is as following:

- Work mac behind firewall, named as 'Victim'. (High Sierra 10.13.3)
- Ubuntu VHS on the net, named as 'server'. Which has ssh running at port 2222. (Ubuntu 16.04)
- other Mac also behind firewall, named as 'attacker'. (High Sierra 10.13.3)

I want to use socks to visit internal websites only accessible from 'victim'.

When I do `ssh -R 5555:localhost:22 serv@server.com -P 2222` from 'victim' and ssh into 'server' from attacker and run `ssh victim@localhost -p 5555`, I have shell access from attacker into the victim.

What I need to achieve is to use socks to visit websites only accessible from the 'victim'..

I understand I should setup a reversed tunnel from the victim to the server and setup some forward on the server from incoming port to the reversed connection port and also setup forwarding on the attacker from localhost to remote (which connects to the server) but how do I do this?

When I setup a socks directly from attacker to server I just run `ssh -D 8080 serv@server.com -p 2222` and setup proxy socks v5 localhost:8080 in Firefox but I don't get how I put up the forward on the server...

Anyone who can explain it to me? Thx

Answer (score 2):

Apparently nobody can answer this question, that's okay because I found the answer myself.

Here is the answers:

- On *victim*: `ssh -N -f -R 5555:localhost:22 -p <port_of_serv> <ip_of_serv>`
- On *attacker* #1: `ssh (-N -f) -L 4444:localhost:5555 -p <port_of_serv> <ip_of_serv>`
- On *attacker* #2: `ssh -p 4444 -D localhost:3333 user_on_victim@localhost`
- On *attacker* #3: in Firefox or irc, or even for the General network settings: Socks (v5) proxy settings: 127.0.0.1 port 3333

Every application you set the host localhost with port 3333 up for will be tunneled via serv to the victim and when you visit something like http://myip.com you'll see the ip/host of the victim. 
From here on you can even use GUI applications on the *attacker* (if you setup socks settings for the specific app or for the system as a whole) which will be tunneled via *serv* to *victim* and you'll act as the *victim* as such.

The mistake I made in my thought process was that I didn't really understand the way the reversed port scheme looks like, I will try to explain it in simple terms.

### Victim action

```
ssh -N -f -R 5555:localhost:22 -p <port_of_serv> <ip_of_serv>
```

- `-N` = I'm not going to run commands in the shell
- `-f` = put the process in the background (so you can close the terminal window)
- `-R` = reversed tunnel
- `5555:localhost:22` = 5555 is the port on which serv internally is listening to put data forward to port 22 on *victim*. If you've setup victim to have ssh run on port 2222 you should change 22 to 2222.
- `-p` = port on which ssh on *serv* is running.

### 1st attack action

```
ssh (-N -f) -L 4444:localhost:5555 -p <port_of_serv> <ip_of_serv>`
```

The 1st command you make on *attacker* (`-L 4444:localhost:5555`) will set up a tunnel so that your connection with your 3rd command will be tunneled right thrue to *victim*. (This is just for Dynamic port forwarding / Socks applications)

If you just want to have shell access on *victim* instead of this command you just ssh in to serv & than run command: 'ssh user_on_victim@localhost -p 5555'.

But we don't want shell access, we want to tunnel all data dynamically so we have to make a port-forward.

#### Or the schematic explanation

- `-L` = local port-forwarding (on *serv*)
- `- 4444:localhost:5555` put all data coming in on port 4444 to port 5555.

### 2nd attack action

The 2nd command you make on *attacker*

ssh -p 4444 -D localhost:3333 user_on_victim@localhost

is the actual command that's going to initialise the connecting through the 2 tunnels. What you do is you say: connect to port 4444 and put all the data that's coming in on (localhost port 3333) to 4444. (which will be put through locally on *serv* to port 5555 -> which will be pushed out to port 22 on *victim*.

#### Or the schematic explanation

- `-D` = Dynamic forwarding
- `localhost:3333` = listen on port 3333 and push data through ssh connection to port 4444 to serv.
- `-p 4444` = the port on which *serv* is listening to put the data forward to port 5555 and than out to port 22 on *victim*.

### 3rd attack action

Setup your applications or even your entire system to use SOCKS (v5) proxy server on address: localhost port: 3333. It does not matter on which ports these applications run normally because that will be handled by the proxy server. In theory every application can run via socks proxy dynamic port forwarding. You'll only have to set it up. :)

The 3rd action on *attacker* is the actual data you're going to tunnel to *victim*. It does not matter what data or application this is, that's why it's dynamic forwarding, it does not matter on which ports these application run because that will be handled by SOCKS.

I hope someone finds use in my explanation.

Have a nice day....

Comment: Awesome! Be sure to mark this answer as solving your problem, so others will know that it works for you.